# when updating an object, what do I call? session.add is for adding, where is update?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/sessions.html

I don't see anything for updating an object that was just retrieved from the database using:

```
q = session.query(products)

for p in q:
     p.blah = 'hello'

     sesion.????
     session.commit()
```

Answer (score 4):

That line `p.blah = 'hello'` *is* updating the property (column) `blah` of the object `p`.

That's the power of object relational mapping in newer languages. Enjoy.

Comment: Also get familiar with the "Unit of Work" concept (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). The session is a "Unit Of Work" in SQLAlchemy (and ORMs in general), which is tracking the status of the "registered" (loaded or newly added) objects automatically.